# How can we help make developer.ubuntu.com better?

Tags: discussion, tags, tools, webapps

The [Ubuntu App Developer website](http://developer.ubuntu.com/) makes use of Ask Ubuntu questions for its "Cookbook" feature. The  App Developer Cookbooks are:

> a collection of short examples, how to’s and answered questions from our developer community. In the sections below you will find information about how to perform common tasks, answers to frequently asked questions, and code snippets from real world examples.

They are generated by [some scripts](https://code.launchpad.net/~mhall119/ubuntudeveloperportal/askubuntu-scripts) that are run manually that filter questions by some parameters (tags, votes, ect) and output html that can be added to the site.

Some of the results could be better. How can we help make AskUbuntu more useful for people wanting to develop apps for Ubuntu and make  make developer.ubuntu.com better?

Comment: UDS session on the topic: http://summit.ubuntu.com/uds-1311/meeting/22023/appdev-1311-better-cookbooks/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In a lot of ways, to be more useful to  developer.ubuntu.com, we just need to do the things that make this site better anyways.

### Better tagging

Questions only show up in the script if they are tagged [application-development](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/application-development). So it's important that questions that might be useful have that tag. It would also be extremely helpful if questions tagged [application-development](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/application-development) also had programing language tags where appropriate.

As the site aims to mostly support the new Ubuntu SDK, getting things tagged [qml](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/qml) would be a great start. When the cookbooks were first generated, the SDK was new and there wasn't much in the [qml](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/qml) tag. Being able to filter on questions that include ***both*** the [application-development](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/application-development) and [qml](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/qml) tag would make the human reviewer's job much easier.

### Up voting

Currently the scripts filter out questions that have less than two votes. Voting up the best questions will allow that threshold to be set higher and help the best content come to the top.

### Hacking

Like hacking in Python? Have experience with the Stack Exchange API? Maybe you have some ideas to make the scripts better? You can check out the [source online](https://code.launchpad.net/~mhall119/ubuntudeveloperportal/askubuntu-scripts) or branch it with:

```
bzr branch lp:~mhall119/ubuntudeveloperportal/askubuntu-scripts
```

Comment: I would filter out questions with negative or 0 voted answers (accepted answers are ok), through I haven't found one in the Cookbook, just in case.

Comment: It currently only looks at questions with accepted answers and +2 or more votes

Comment: We also have [tag:ubuntu-sdk].